# iPhone - NSScanner does not parse

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, nsstring, nsscanner

I'm using this method to find the first <> couple into a string (XML content) :

```
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:contentToParse];
int startPos = 0;
int endPos = 0;

// Open search
if ([scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:nil]) {
    startPos = [scanner scanLocation]-1;
    NSLog(@"found '<' at pos %i", startPos);

    // close search
    if ([scanner scanString:@">" intoString:nil]) {
        endPos = [scanner scanLocation]-1;
        NSLog(@"found '>' at pos %i", endPos);

        NSString* tag = [contentToParse substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPos, endPos-startPos)];
        NSLog(@"Tag found : %@", tag);
    }
}
```

but only "found '<' at pos 0" is logged.
My XML content contains many many <> items...

Why is that method not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanString:intoString:` tries to scan the string parameter **at the current location**. If such string is not present at the current location, it simply returns `NO`.

You may want use `scanUpToString:intoString:` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanUpToString%3aintoString%3a)) instead, which scans advancing the scan location until the given string is encountered.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:contentToParse];
// open search
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:nil];
if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    [scanner scanString:@"<" intoString:nil];
    // close search
    NSString *tag = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&tag];
    if (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
        NSLog(@"Tag found : %@", tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But why ` [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:nil];
    if (true) ..............` works (al logs are fine) and why | if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:nil]) .............. don't (not a single piece of log into the console) ?

Comment: `[scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:nil]`returns NO... strange ? I didn't change charactersToBeSkipped... TIP : I have a < caracter at the beginning of the file. Would that be the reason ???

Comment: @Oliver `scanUpToString:intoString:` returns `YES` **if the scanner scans any characters**. If you have a "<" character at the beginning it returns `NO`. You don't want to use the return value of this method to check whether it found the string or not. Use `![scanner isAtEnd]` like in my example.